# Splattering your brain all over meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

In a book I'm reading there is a sentence like this

> This is difficult to imagine without
>   splattering your brains all over the person next to you as you read this

Here is the situation:

> But how can an infinite universe be consistent with what we see? Can a universe be infinite and expand from a Big Bang? Yes, but only if you don’t assume the Big Bang started from a single spot. Imagine a Big Bang that happened everywhere at the same time. This is difficult to imagine without
>   splattering your brains all over the person next to you as you read this, but it’s also totally consistent with what we observe.

My question is what does Splattering your brain all over the person mean?

I have searched in many dictionaries and google but I couldn't find the phrase "splatter sth over sb" there.

Please explain to me.

Thanks.

Comment: I feel as though this is idiomatic. It does not mean literally having your brain splatter all over the person next to you. I think it means that you are having your mind blown away by cool information.

Comment: It's not idiomatic because the expression is not used often enough. But it's a new twist on the 'mind being blown away' metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

from the accepted idiom:  **blow someone’s mind** [free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+someone%E2%80%99s+mind)

> to impress someone; to overwhelm someone. "This whole business just
>   blows my mind".

use of **splatter** used as adj: [free dict](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/splatter)

> 4. characterized by gory imagery

Splattering your brains ... just adds an element of a gore.

Comment: Nowadays we sometimes say a startling concept “makes my head/brain explode”.

Answer (score 0):

Where some known knowledge gets in your brain and stirs up incomprehensible amazement never to be really fully grasped or understood....to be expected and acceptable by an instructor (who may not know all about it either..!)